# How to use webdriver-manager clean to remove all downloaded files?

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

After every run i wish to delete all files that webdriver-manager downloaded as webdriver-manager start fails in subsequent runs inside proxy network. 
When i run webdriver-manager clean command in console it works fine but when the same command is run via nodejas it throws an error

command : npm run driver-clean
script: driver-clean: 'webdriver-manager clean'
Error : Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\mithun\ui-automation\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver
_75.0.3770.140.exe'

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the chromeDriver.exe instance is not closed after test run.Try to run the below command after your test

`node ./node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager clean`

**OR**

to kill your chrome driver from command line use : `taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f 
//To confirm the chrome driver name check task manager after starting the chrome driver.`

Hope it helps you